# Consensus Clustering in python with big dataset

Tags: python, cluster-analysis, consensus

I have found a very nice implementation for Consensus Clustering in python [here](https://github.com/ZigaSajovic/Consensus_Clustering/blob/master/consensusClustering.py)

However, for large datasets with large sample size, the algorithm will not work since it builds matrices with dimension [samples, samples].

Is there any efficient python implementation for Consensus Clustering on large datasets?

Answer (score 2):

I am facing a similar problem where I need to do consensus clustering on a large dataset that would result in a 1,000,000 x 1,000,000 consensus matrix (hopefully pretty sparse *fingers crossed*). While I have not solved this problem yet, I have found some leads in the paper: [Accelerating high-dimensional clustering with lossless data reduction](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC5870568/) where they develop their own R algorithm for lossless data reduction and then use the R package [ConsensusClusterPlus](https://bioconductor.org/packages/release/bioc/html/ConsensusClusterPlus.html). I know this isn't a real answer and is implemented in R and not Python, but hopefully it points people, like it did  me, in the right direction!

**UPDATE**

I ended up implementing the consensus clustering algorithm described in [this paper](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S131915781930597X) in python [here](https://github.com/MattHodgman/celluster). On a dataset with over 1,000,000 cells and around 50 features, I was able to run individual clustering algorithms such as [FastPG](https://github.com/sararselitsky/FastPG) in a matter of minutes and then use those results as input into the consensus clustering algorithm which also ran in a matter of minutes.